# How to extend Admin Cart rules controller?

Tags: php, prestashop

I am working on a custom module that will allow to generate `N` of vouchers at the same time.
I need all the functionality of the current Cart Rules. I am looking at the `AdminCartRulesController` and ofcourse all the code is there.

How can I "extend" or copy and modify it so that I will add one more input to the form, and the loop adding to database by form value? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the file:
override\controllers\admin\AdminCartRulesController.php

overriding the Core file the following way:

```
<?php
class AdminCartRulesController extends AdminCartRulesControllerCore
{
}
```

and there to override the methods you need.

Do not forget the clear the classes index (deleting cache/class_index.php) after adding the file.

Comment: @PrestaShop-developer.cc: Thank you for that. So, I should just copy all the code from the default controller and change it to my needs ?

Comment: Copy ONLY the methods you need to change - the rest will be just inherited.

Comment: @PrestaShop-developer.cc Thank you! I managed to override the form and some stuff in the controller. Now, how does the processAdd, afterAdd, postProcess functions work ? Is there any documentation? 
I am loooking for a way, to add multiple same records for Cart Rule. I tried to add a FOR statement in afterAdd around all the code, but each cart rule still gets inserted only once.